# extjs - center a formPanel on a web page

Tags: html, css, extjs

Using extjs, I have a formPanel with a fixed width. I want to Center this form within a normal wep page so the form keep appears in the center even i minimize the browser. i didn't use an outer container, just a simple form panel with html/css page. so the following wouldn't work in my case:

```
layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'center',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Centered Panel',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two other containers (left and right) with `flex` = 1 and change the layout to `hbox`:

```
layout: {
    type: 'hbox'
},
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    flex: 1
},{
    title: 'Centered Panel',
    width: 200,
    height: 200
},    {
    xtype: 'container',
    flex: 1
}]
```